# Homomorphism between ideal sheaves of codimension $2$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety with two different reduced subschemes $Z,Y\subset X$ which induced from ideal sheaves $\mathscr{I}_Z,\mathscr{I}_Y$. If codimensions of them are both larger than $2$, why $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathscr{I}_Z,\mathscr{I}_Y)=0$?

I think this may be a very stupid question but I can't understand here...

My situation, we consider:

> Fix a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $6$.
> Pick a general linear subspace $L\subset \mathbb{P}\left(\bigwedge^2V\right)$
> of dimension $8$. Then we consider
> $$S:=\mathrm{Pf}(2,V)\cap L,\quad W:=\mathrm{Pf}(4,V^{\vee})\cap L^{\bot}.$$
> It's easy to see that $S$ is a smooth K3 surface of degree $14$ and $W$ is a smooth cubic
> fourfold.
>
> Consider $\Gamma:=\{(s,w)\in S\times W:s\cap\ker w\neq0\}$ with projections $p_W:\Gamma\to W$ and $p_S:\Gamma\to S$. Let $\Gamma_p=p_S^{-1}(p)$. For $p\neq q$ we can show that $\Gamma_p\neq\Gamma_q$ are two distinct surface which have codimension $2$. Why $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathscr{I}_{\Gamma_p},\mathscr{I}_{\Gamma_q})=0$?

Actually I don't know what is the real meaning of the morphisms of ideals.
Maybe we can associated them into the sequence $0\to\mathscr{I}_{\Gamma_p}\to\mathscr{O}_W\to\mathscr{O}_{\Gamma_p}\to0$?

---

Thank you for your any help!

Comment: Hint: Show that $\operatorname{Hom} (\mathcal{I}_Y, \mathcal{O}_X)=k$, a one dimensional vector space.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main observation is that, if $Y \subset X$ and $\operatorname{codim}(Y) \ge 2$ then
$$
(I_Y)^\vee \cong \mathcal{O}_X,
\qquad\text{hence}\qquad
(I_Y)^{\vee\vee} \cong \mathcal{O}_X.
$$
Now assume $\phi \colon I_Z \to I_Y$ is a nontrivial morphism. The by functoriality of the double dual, it gives a morphism
$$
\mathcal{O}_X \cong (I_Z)^{\vee\vee} 
\stackrel{\phi^{\vee\vee}}\longrightarrow
(I_Y)^{\vee\vee} \cong \mathcal{O}_X,
$$
which is compatible with the natural morphisms
$$
I_Z \to (I_Z)^{\vee\vee} \cong \mathcal{O}_X
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
I_Y \to (I_Y)^{\vee\vee} \cong \mathcal{O}_X
$$
(because this is a natural transformation). Since any endomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a multiplication by a constant, it follows that $\phi$ is an embedding of ideals $I_Z \subset I_Y$, hence $Y \subset Z$.

Comment: Is the assertion that $ (I_Y)^{\vee} = \mathcal{O}_X $ a consequence of the following steps: (1) $ (I_Y)^{\vee} $ is reflexive by a short lemma (2) $ (I_Y)^{\vee \vee} = \mathcal{O}_X $ because the double dual is a line bundle which is trivial outside a codimension $ 2 $ closed subset, hence is trivial by Hartog's lemma. I don't immediately see how you get the first dual trivial and then the second.

Comment: @CraniumClamp: Start with the standard exact sequence $$0 \to I_Y \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0$$, apply the dualization functor, and use the fact that $$\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_X) = \mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_X) = 0$$ since the codimension of $Y$ is at least 2.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you for your nice solution!

Comment: @Sasha Sorry for my stupid questions, why $\mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathscr{O}_Y,\mathscr{O}_X)=0$? Is this just a direct calculation?

Comment: @Sasha I think this is right if $\mathrm{depth}_{I_Y}O_X\geq2$，maybe we need use some kind of Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: @Sasha Oh I'm sorry, this may follows from $\mathscr{depth}_{I_Y}(\mathscr{O}_X)=\inf\{\mathrm{depth}(\mathscr{O}_{X,x}):x\in V(I_Y)\}$ and the Serre's criterion for normality.

Comment: One way to see that $\mathcal{E}xt^1(\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_X) = 0$ is by using the  local-to-global spectral sequence and Serre duality on $X$.